# What to do with: "You may only load the closed dialog every 3 seconds"

Tags: bug, status-norepro, closing, user-interface, rate-limiting

If I try to close a question then the following text appears:

"You may only load the closed dialog every 3 seconds"

and closing is not possible.

I encounter this problem not on my own computer.

Comment: Does it happen all the time or just sometimes? Did you try to wait for a while and do it again? Most every action on SE is rate limited and sometimes one can trigger this by a miss click.

Comment: @quid It happens all the time (also "flag" doesn't work). I have tried it several times. I am not home now and am working on different computer. Home I have never been bothered with this. BTW, it is not urgent, but a week ago I had the same problem on this computer. So I thought: maybe it's wise to bring it under attention. Thank you for editing.

Comment: Yes, if it happens all the time it is quite weird. Could you give some details on that computer, especially the browser and OS?

Comment: @quid Internet explorer and windows 7. Here I am logged in with a mathexchange account. At home I usually use google account. Maybe that plays a part in this?

Comment: Could it be that your mouse accidentally sends two click-events?

Comment: @DanielFischer No, that is not the case. Or at least there is nothing else that indicates that.

Comment: @DanielFischer Don't bother too much about it. Tomorrow I am home again and after one or two weeks I am working on this computer again and will see if the problem still exists. It is a good thing that the question has been asked. If others have the same problem then they can recognize this question. If it is indeed a matter of "computer" then you are probably quite powerless (unless I underestimate you here). Thanks for the attention.

Comment: @quid Don't bother too much about it. Tomorrow I am home again and after one or two weeks I am working on this computer again and will see if the problem still exists. It is a good thing that the question has been asked. If others have the same problem then they can recognize this question. If it is indeed a matter of "computer" then you are probably quite powerless (unless I underestimate you here). Thanks for the attention.

Comment: Closing as [meta-tag:status-norepro] - I can't make this happen, and without exact steps to reproduce...

Comment: @Oded, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280019/if-question-is-closed-already-when-i-try-to-review-close-votes-error-message-is